# convert date to a different format

Tags: date, zend-date

I have a date of the form mm-dd-yyyy. I need to convert into YYYY-MM-dd to store in the database.
I did the following

```
$eff_date=$this->post['effective_date'];
$eff_date=$eff_date->toString('YYYY-MM-dd');
```

I get the following error:

Call to a member function toString() on a non-object

I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$eff_date is a Zend_Date object? or just a string? if it's just a string you will need to instance the Zend_Date object first:

```
<?php
$eff_date = new Zend_Date($this->post['effective_date'], 'mm-dd-yyyy', 'en');
$eff_date = $eff_date->get('YYYY-MM-dd');
```

Comment: thanks @mario ..now if i retrieve it from the database to display. Do i reconvert it into mm/dd/yyy in the same way?

Comment: Reconvert to store in the DB? yes, definitively.   I recommend you if you're using Zend, you may look into using Zend_DB to use models, this way it will be more transparent, you now like just giving the Zend_Date object and it will convert it to the proper DB Date String.

Comment: Use Zend_Filter to normalize it before you store it into the database.